# EF insert Record in Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm new in entity framework concept. I create model for Userlist and roles that will determine there respected access. User can have many roles and role could have many user

```
 public class TblUser
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogIn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string ResetPassword { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string ResetNewPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResetPasswordExpire { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public List<TblRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class TblRole
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string RoleID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<TblUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

here is my database
[image]

I'm trying now to add new user using code below but i getting this error 
{"constraint failed\r\nUNIQUE constraint failed: TblRole.RoleID"}

```
public string addNewUser(string Username, string Email, Model.DB.TblRole roles)
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            ExpenseMonitoringSystem.Controller.Security sec = new Security();
            string randomPassword = sec.Encrypt(RandomString(6, false));

            if((from user in db.TblUser where user.UserName==Username select user).FirstOrDefault()!=null)
                throw new Exception("The username is already used");
            if ((from user in db.TblUser where user.EMailAddress == Email select user).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                throw new Exception("The email is already used");

            var newuser = new ExpenseMonitoringSystem.Model.DB.TblUser
                {
                    UserID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Password = randomPassword,
                    UserName = Username,
                    ResetPassword = "YES",
                    ResetNewPassword = randomPassword,
                    ResetPasswordExpire = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                    EMailAddress = Email,
                    Active = "YES",
                    Roles = new List<Model.DB.TblRole>() { roles }
                };

            db.TblUser.Add(newuser);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return randomPassword;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note for duplication check, `if ((from user in db.TblUser where user.EMailAddress == Email select user).FirstOrDefault() != null)` can be written as `if (db.TblUser.Any(user => user.EMailAddress == Email))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> constraint failed\r\nUNIQUE constraint failed: TblRole.RoleID

could mean that you're trying to add a `TblRole` to your database but there's already an existing record that has the same `RoleID`.

Looking at your code, it looks like you're getting the `roles` somewhere and then you create a new instance of `DatabaseContext`, `db`. The issue is that `db` thinks that `roles` are new records when you called `db.TblUser.Add(newuser)`. To tell `db` that `roles` are already in the database, you could call `db.TblRole.Attach` on each `TblRole` in `roles` before adding `newUser`.

You can [learn more about that concept (entity states) here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state).

Answer (score 0):

Configure a **Many-to-Many Relationship** using Fluent API

You can learn more about entity Relationship [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)